# ng-repeat em arquivo JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-repeat

Estou montando um menu com `ng-repeat="espaco in espacos"`. Até ai tranquilo.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="espaco in espacos"><a href="" ng-click="selected(espaco)">{{espaco.nome}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

No controler estou recuperando o "espaco" clicado e devolvendo as informações sobre ele vindas de um JSON, onde alguns "espacos" tem mais de uma imagem pra exibir.

Na div que exibe as imagens estou usando `ng-repeat="img in i"` mas as imagens não estão sendo atualizadas quando clico em outro item do menu(outro espaço), aparecendo o seguinte erro:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
```

Comment: Resolvi. Na verdade o índice imagemUrl do JSON é um array então, independentemente de um espaço ter 01 ou 1000 imagens ele deve ser representado como um array, ou seja, "imagemUrl": [ 'caminhoDaImagem.png' ] com os colchetes. Resumindo o problema era apenas a ausencia dos colchetes no JSON.